# Node JS Array of Objects - get indexOf

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

I have an array of objects. I am attempting to locate the index of an object inside this array, however it always returns -1 unless I "cheat". I cannot see the difference here and it console.logs the exact same output both ways. It only works one way... Is this a bug?

```
var arr = [{ un: 'test', uid: 1 }];
console.log("array",arr,typeof arr);

var obj = { un: 'test', uid: 1};
console.log("obj",obj);

console.log(arr[0],typeof arr[0]);
console.log("indexOf",arr.indexOf(obj));

arr.push(obj);
console.log(arr);
console.log("indexOf",arr.indexOf(obj));
```

The Output is this:

```
array [ { un: 'test', uid: 1 } ] object
obj { un: 'test', uid: 1 }
{ un: 'test', uid: 1 } 'object'
indexOf -1
[ { un: 'test', uid: 1 }, { un: 'test', uid: 1 } ]
indexOf 1
```

For the life of me, I cannot see the difference here. Am I missing something simple here? It's possible... considering the hours of coding, simple things get overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, Objects are always references to the object itself (pointers to memory address where the object is stored), so doing

```
var arr = [{ un: 'test', uid: 1 }];
var obj = { un: 'test', uid: 1};
console.log("obj",obj);
```

will never return anything else than -1 because obj has a different address than the object in arr. That's why, if you push `obj`in `arr` it does work.

So `Array.prototype.indexOf` with an object as an argument will look for the same reference, whereas `Array.prototype.indexOf` with number, string, null will look for the value.

If you want to find the index of an object with specific properties use :

```
var arr = [{ un: 'test', uid: 1 }];
var index = arr.findIndex(i => i.un === 'test' && i.uid === 1);
```

Here is the doc for findIndex : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand. Is there a different method for obtaining the index of the object inside the array without a 'for' loop or some syntax of lodash?

Comment: I added the example with `.findIndex`method. You don't need lodash :)

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for your assistance here. Been very helpful. I tried findIndex before but I must have typo'd because it was reporting an invalid function. Sometimes I've noticed that node.js doesn't have all the prototypes that javascript does so I apparently didn't look close enough.

Comment: It is true, ECMA standards are ahead of most Javascript implementations. Javascript itself is a specification, like a protocol or a norm, then multiple engines implement it, but obviously like any norm it is always ahead of its implementations. In rare cases, implementations will define the norm, it happended I believe with the Promise class.